# Scope of locks on a database row (Simple)

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, oracle

If I locked a row inside a method, and then called that method from another method inside the same class, would it retain the lock?

Locked row method has (as a prepared statement):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE row_name IN (?) FOR UPDATE
```

This method would take those selected and make a list (or array). 
Then a method in the same class would call the locked row method in order to get the list/array and do the actual updates.

Also note that I do want to have these in two different methods in the same thread (it is concurrent).

So, does it keep the lock for the updating method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database locks are not associated with Java classes or any other Java construct.  They are associated with a Database transaction.  Any work done within the transaction will be done with the lock.  Any work done in a different transaction will be blocked by the lock.

Comment: In that case, I would also have to have the same Connection in order for it to be a single locked transaction?

Comment: @Brian - yes, a given transaction is associated with a specific Connection instance.